# Why are CSS cursor types so rare on the web?

Tags: web-app, css, cursor

Coming across [this handy CSS Cursor tool](http://css-cursor.techstream.org/) I wondered: why are the CSS cursor types other than `default`, `pointer` and `text` so rare on the web? Even most web applications don't go further than these three plus perhaps cursors for moving and grabbing.

Comment: That site seems to only cover CSS2 keywords for the `cursor` property. [CSS UI 3](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-ui/#cursor) has more, including potentially useful `zoom-in`/`zoom-out`, but no ‘zoom-fullscreen’ or ‘zoom-originalsize’ or ‘pointer-opensnewtaborwindow’.

Comment: default, pointer and text. Then you have one more used cursor than _most desktop applications_. If I don't need it I would refrain to _learn_ meaning of fancy cursors, random icons bother me enough...

Comment: Personally, I never use them mainly because I didn't know half of those existed as CSS options. Combine that with the fact that I rarely have to use them (I think disabled is the only one I touch sometimes). Most plugins such as jQuery UI Resizable comes with the cursor CSS built in so I always assumed it was some sort of browser default implementation.

Comment: Changing the cursor is irritating unless it's for a specific purpose, and increasingly irrelevant on touch devices.

Comment: To show your user exotic cursor types you must first be sure that they already know them, else you don't. Thus, they don't see those fancy pointers and they don't learn them.  You need somebody else to teach your users about them   :-)

Answer (score 18):

**I think you've answered your own question.**

The special cursors demonstrated on that web site are rarely needed, whether in a browser or outside of one. Of the 31 cursors, 14 of them are for resizing elements, which isn't really a common task.

Comment: The lifehacker network of sites uses `crosshair` when hovering images. I'm not so sure I like that decision but hey, what do I know.

Comment: @mikeTheLiar That's caused by their image-commenting plugin (I don't know its name), so that the crosshair is for aiming at the exact point in which you insert your comment. I always intended it like this, anyway

Answer (score 15):

I see Progress and Help used fairly regularly.

Other than that, the rest of them are mostly situational... there's no need to use them out of specific tasks and environments.

Using cursors where not absolutely necessary violates the rule of **don't confuse your users, ever**. If you can use a normal cursor, do.

Answer (score 11):

"**Default**", "**Pointer**" and "**Text**" are defaults in browsers.

Others we forget to specify for developer — because we paint static images. But if we work with interaction our-self, we will remember to use "**Not available**" cursor for disabled elements for example.

Answer (score 2):

In most cases the cursor primarily is to SELECT, POINT or CLICK. Extra actions such as GRAB, CROSSHAIRS are handy for other more specific type applications like picture uploads, crop and resizing.

[image: Upload image resizing]